# pyodbc.Error: ('00000', '[00000] [IBM][Controlador ODBC de System i Access]Argumento de tipo de datos SQL fuera de rango. (30030) (SQLBindParameter)')

Tags: python, python-3.x, base-de-datos, tkinter, db2

Tengo un formulario en Python con Tkinter, y todo lo que el usuario ponga en las diferentes entradas lo quiero almacenar en una base de datos DB2. Esta es la sentencia para insertar:

```
registrar_intervencion_cursor = conn_db2.cursor()

insertar_centro = centro_desplegable.get()
insertar_intervencion = tipo_intervencion_desplegable.get()
insertar_subtipo_intervencion = subtipo_intervencion_desplegable.get()
insertar_comentario = comentario_entrada.get()
insertar_producto_final = referencia_producto_final_entrada.get()
insertar_componente = referencia_producto_final_entrada.get()
insertar_util = util_entrada.get()
insertar_tiempo = tiempo_aprox_intervencion_entrada.get()


registrar_intervencion_query = "INSERT INTO BIUMO220.TICKREGINTERVENCION(numerador, responsable, fecha, centro, tipo_intervencion, subtipo, comentario, ref_producto_final, df_producto_final, ref_componente, df_componente, util, df_util, tiempo_intervencion) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
registrar_intervencion_cursor.execute(registrar_intervencion_query, numerador, uname, fecha_hoy, insertar_centro, insertar_intervencion, insertar_subtipo_intervencion, insertar_comentario, insertar_producto_final, res, insertar_componente, componente_resultado, insertar_util, util_resultado, insertar_tiempo)
registrar_intervencion_cursor.commit()
```

Pero me salta el siguiente error cuando intento hacerlo:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('00000', '[00000] [IBM][Controlador ODBC de System i Access]Argumento de tipo de datos SQL fuera de rango. (30030) (SQLBindParameter)')
```

Comment: ¿Quizás sea por los paréntesis: `registrar_intervencion_cursor.execute(registrar_intervencion_query, (numerador, uname, fecha_hoy, insertar_centro, insertar_intervencion, insertar_subtipo_intervencion, insertar_comentario, insertar_producto_final, res, insertar_componente, componente_resultado, insertar_util, util_resultado, insertar_tiempo))`?

Comment: No, sigue saltando el mismo error aunque lo ponga así.